# Changing HTML content with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong with this code? Nothing is happening when I click the link. First I have PHP a user's bio with a link below to edit it (keep in mind this script is in an external file that is included into the main)...

```
<?php

/* bio was retrieved earlier... */

echo '<div id="bio">
<p>'.$row["bio"].'<br>
<a href="javascript:editBio(\''.$row["bio"].'\');">Edit</a></p>
</div>';

?>
```

Then I have a javascript function in the main file that I want to replace the div with a form...

```
function editBio(bio) {

    document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = '
    <form action="profile.editbio.php" method="post">
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="bio" id="bio" maxlength="275">'+ bio +'</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update"></form>
    ';

}
```

What I want is for the user to click the "Edit" link and have their bio instantly turn into a textarea where they can edit it.

When checking the console I got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you can provide shorter, less complicated code (although I don't think you could) that would be great!

Comment: So...does it *not* work?

Comment: @AstroCB - edited to include what happens.

Comment: Did you happen to check the console while you were attempting to run this?

Comment: @jsickles It says `I also checked for errors with the developer tool in Chrome and saw nothing.`

Comment: The error you indicated means that the $row['bio'] is not being treated as a string, but rather a variable or method call (which probably doesn't exist, which is why you're getting an undefined error)

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` means your code is not properly ended try to use color coded editor so you may see the difference of your posted code and when it is concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's because of the line breaks in your HTML: when your line drops off, it's breaking to the next line rather than overflowing.

It should look like this:

```
document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = '<form action="profile.editbio.php" method="post"><textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="bio" id="bio" maxlength="275">'+ bio +'</textarea><br><input type="submit" value="Update"></form>';
```

The parentheses don't carry through the line breaks.

Also, as jsickles mentioned, this line is going to give you an error:

```
<a href="javascript:editBio('.$row["bio"].');">Edit</a>
```

You need to escape the inner parentheses:

```
<a href="javascript:editBio('.$row[\'bio\'].');">Edit</a>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/7agnW/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer combined with @jsickles 's is what solved my problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with echoing the string `'<a href="javascript:editBio('.$row["bio"].');">Edit</a>'`. `$row` is a php variable.

Comment: @mclaassen The quotation marks around `bio` break the string (see the coloring of that line in my answer).

Comment: @AstroCB That's because you don't have opening and closing single quotes around them, which there would be if the string was properly concatenated on each new line.

Answer (score 1):

new line values must be concatenated, like this:

```
function editBio(bio) {

    document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = '<form action="profile.editbio.php" method="post">'
                                                +'<textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="bio" id="bio" maxlength="275">'+ bio +'</textarea><br>'
                                                +'<input type="submit" value="Update"></form>';

}
```

Comment: The concatenation is not necessary: just put it all on one line.

Comment: but in your code example your the code seems to be in new line. so you should do the concatenation.

Comment: It doesn't matter; it will work either way, but concatenating them is unnecessary work.

Comment: your error means your code is not properly ended `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. try to use color coded editor to see the difference.

Comment: @mclaassen That's fair enough, but it wasn't mentioned in the answer. I just have an issue with the wording "*must* be concatenated".

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you're not using quotes around the function call parameter.

```
<a href="javascript:editBio(\''.$row["bio"].'\');">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Now the styntax error is this: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @Locke please update your question with the exact changes you've made so far - and also what is the value in the "bio" field

Comment: @Locke don't forget to post the value of `$row['bio']`, please

Comment: That's not the problem. It would be correctly quoted if the line itself was concatenated properly.

Comment: Thanks, your answer combined with @AstroCB 's is what solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't this code...

```
javascript:editBio('.$row["bio"].');
```

need to me in the 'a' onclick event rather than the href atrribute ?

eg.

```
<a href="javascript:editBio('.$row["bio"].');">Edit</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="" onclick="editBio('.$row["bio"].');">Edit</a>
```

Comment: These both do the same thing.